# Ruby .where count only once duplicated results

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In my Rails 6/Grape API app I've got a model `SurveyResult` where I store results of survey which user filed.

It's possible to have few survey results for a given question (it can be a multiple choice question):

```
[31] pry(main)> SurveyResult.where(survey: survey, user: user)
 #<SurveyResult:0x00007f9283adca10
  id: 18,
  user_id: 1,
  survey_id: 1,
  cms_question_id: 5844869,
  cms_answer_id: 321,

 #<SurveyResult:0x00007f9283adc7e0
  id: 20,
  user_id: 1,
  survey_id: 1,
  cms_question_id: 5899779,
  cms_answer_id: 0987,

 #<SurveyResult:0x00007f9283adc920
  id: 21,
  user_id: 1,
  survey_id: 1,
  cms_question_id: 5899779,
  cms_answer_id: 12,
```

For example there are two results for the same `cms_question_id` - `5899779` (as above). Now if I want to count all user `SurveyResults` I will get below result:

```
[31] pry(main)> SurveyResult.where(survey: survey, user: user).count
=> 3
```

How to modify this query to count `SurveyResult` with the same `cms_question_id` only once? The expected result for above example should be:

```
[31] pry(main)> SurveyResult.where(survey: survey, user: user).count
=> 2
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looking at the [`count`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Calculations.html#method-i-count) documentation that would be:

```
SurveyResult.where(survey: survey, user: user).distinct.count(:cms_question_id)
```

> #### count(column_name = nil)
>
> Count the records.
>
> ```
> Person.count
> # => the total count of all people
>
> Person.count(:age)
> # => returns the total count of all people whose age is present in database
>
> Person.count(:all)
> # => performs a COUNT(*) (:all is an alias for '*')
>
> Person.distinct.count(:age)
> # => counts the number of different age values
> ```